# How to get arithmetically growing minor ticks with matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

The following snippet creates a list `myHLines` of (`y`) values that is arithmetically growing.

I want to use them as minor y ticks in a matplotlib plot.

How can I do this?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 3, 10, 30, 100]})

myMin = df.a.min()
myMax = df.a.max()
ratio = 3
myHLines = [myMin * ratio ** i for i in range(1000) if myMin * ratio ** i < myMax]

print("myHLines=", myHLines)
# myHLines= [1, 3, 9, 27, 81]

plt.plot(df, '-o', markersize=2, c='r')

plt.show()
```

Comment: As suggested by you, I updated my question accordingly. Unfortunately, the `minor=True` option does not seem to exist.

Comment: `plt.gca().set_yticks(myHLines, minor=True)`?

Comment: Yes, this solves my question. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Is the scale of the y-axis you want to achieve the y-axis shown in the graph below?

```
plt.plot(df, '-o', markersize=2, c='r')
locs, labels = plt.yticks()
new_y = sorted(myHLines + locs.tolist()[1:-1])
# print(new_y)
plt.yticks(new_y)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this solves my question. But I think the solution of @JohanC in his comment is a little bit more straightforward.